# Detect model name and firmware version of CCTV Camera

Tags: version, firmware

The script try to detect camera model name and firmware version of dahua camera but therse is som issue I couldn't fix it?
It seems the script indicates that the Dahua camera at the specified IP address is not responding to HTTP requests!
The camera is powered on and connected to the network. I'm also accessing the camera's web interface from a different web browser.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import http.client
import re
import requests

# Define the predefined URIs to send HTTP requests to
URIS = [
   "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getDeviceInfo",
   "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getCameraInfo",
   "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getRecordSchedule",
   "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getSystemCfg",
   "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getNetworkCfg"
]

# Define the user agent to use when sending HTTP requests
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

def send_http_request(host, uri, user_agent=USER_AGENT):
   """Sends an HTTP request to the specified host and URI and returns the response."""
   headers = {
       "User-Agent": user_agent
   }

   response = requests.get(f"http://{host}{uri}", headers=headers)
   if response.status_code == 200:
       return response.content
   else:
       raise Exception(f"Failed to send HTTP request to {uri}: {response.status_code}")

def detect_dahua_camera(host):
   """Detects the model and firmware version of a Dahua camera and returns a dictionary containing the results."""
   results = {}

   # Iterate over the predefined URIs and send HTTP requests
   for uri in URIS:
       try:
           response = send_http_request(host, uri)
       except Exception as e:
           print(f"[!] Error sending HTTP request to {uri}: {e}")
           continue

       # Search the response for the model name using the updated regex pattern
       model_match = re.search(MODEL_NAME_REGEX, response)
       if model_match:
           results["model_name"] = model_match.group(1).strip()

       # Search the response for the firmware version using the updated regex pattern
       version_match = re.search(FIRMWARE_VERSION_REGEX, response)
       if version_match:
           results["firmware_version"] = version_match.group(1).strip()

       # If both model name and firmware version are found, break out of the loop
       if "model_name" in results and "firmware_version" in results:
           break

   results.setdefault("model_name", None)
   results.setdefault("firmware_version", None)

   return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Get the IP address from the command-line argument
   host = sys.argv[1]

   results = detect_dahua_camera(host)

   # Print the results to the console
   if results:
       print(f"[+] Model name: {results.get('model_name') or 'Could not detect model name'}")
       print(f"[+] Firmware version: {results.get('firmware_version') or 'Could not detect firmware version'}")
   else:
       print("[!] Unable to detect the model and firmware version of the Dahua camera")
```

The output of python dahua_detect.py 192.198.02.123

```
[!] Error sending HTTP request to /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getDeviceInfo: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[!] Error sending HTTP request to /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getCameraInfo: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[!] Error sending HTTP request to /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getRecordSchedule: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[!] Error sending HTTP request to /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getSystemCfg: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[!] Error sending HTTP request to /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=getNetworkCfg: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[+] Model name: Could not detect model name
[+] Firmware version: Could not detect firmware version
```